# How make up an infinite loop of two jQuery animation effects?

Tags: jquery

How make up an infinite loop of two jQuery animation effects: one does `$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#000'}, 'slow');`, after that the other does `$('body').animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 'slow');`, then start over again: from `#000` to '#fff'. All that in an infinite loop.

Comment: Just a note: as a designer, I suggest you avoid changing the background color of the body of any web page, regardless of its function. It confuses and frustrates users, and makes text hard to read in different places and at different times.

Answer (score 11):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YS5DE/

```
var $body = $(document.body),cycle;

(cycle = function() {
   $body.animate({backgroundColor:"#000"}, 'slow')
        .animate({backgroundColor:"#FFF"}, 'slow',cycle);
})();
```

You can easily add in some delays if you want:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YS5DE/1/

```
var $body = $(document.body),cycle;

(cycle = function() {
   $body.delay(1000)
        .animate({backgroundColor:"#000"}, 'slow')
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({backgroundColor:"#FFF"}, 'slow',cycle);
})();
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of ,cycle in the var $body

Comment: @alex: Just declaring the variable. You can do multiple comma separated declarations with one `var` keyword. It is the same as `var $body = $(...); var cycle;`. It may look like it is part of `$body` because it's on the same line.

Comment: I was assuming we can do without it, but this is probably safer.